# Изменить цвет подчеркивания richTextBox WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Возможно ли поменять цвет подчеркивания и его форму в Windows Forms richTextBox, чтобы было примерно похоже на Microsoft Word подчеркивании, при обнаружении ошибки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Должно помочь, не волнистое, но всё же красное.

```
richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Underline);
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
```